# выдаёт ошибки в части кода css

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Консоль выдаёт 6 ошибок в css части кода, которые не понимаю, как исправить. Из-за данных ошибок не часть css кода вообще не работает.

Вот часть css кода:

```css
  @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Jost|Suez+One&display=swap');
{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  outline: none;
}

body,
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background-color: #000;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px 0, 5% 0px 0.5%;
  background: transparent;
  float: left;
  position: fixed;
}

header #logo {
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}

header #logo span {
  font-size: 1.7em;
  line-height: 45px;
  margin-left: 40px;
  font-family: 'Suez One', serif;
}

@media (min-width: 701px) {
  #logo {
    float: left;
    width: 30%;
    font-size: 1.1em;
  }
  @media (max-width: 700px) {
    #logo {
      margin-top: 15px;
      width: 100%;
      font-size: 1.5em;
    }
  }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: селектор для стилей "margin: 0 etc" не указали

Comment: но лучше выкладывать с html примеры кода

Answer (score 0):

```css
  @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Jost|Suez+One&display=swap');
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  outline: none;
}

body,
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background-color: #000;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  background: transparent;
  float: left;
  position: fixed;
}

header #logo {
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}

header #logo span {
  font-size: 1.7em;
  line-height: 45px;
  margin-left: 40px;
  font-family: 'Suez One', serif;
}

@media (min-width: 701px) {
  #logo {
    float: left;
    width: 30%;
    font-size: 1.1em;
  }
  @media (max-width: 700px) {
    #logo {
      margin-top: 15px;
      width: 100%;
      font-size: 1.5em;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Jost|Suez+One&display=swap');
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  outline: none;
}

body,
html {
  width: 100hv;
  height: 100wv;
}

body {
  background-color: #000;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica;
}

header {
  width: 100wv;
  padding: 10px;
  background: transparent;
  float: left;
  position: fixed;
}

header #logo {
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}

header #logo span {
  font-size: 1.7em;
  line-height: 45px;
  margin-left: 40px;
  font-family: 'Suez One', serif;
}

@media (min-width: 701px) {
  #logo {
    float: left;
    width: 30%;
    font-size: 1.1em;} 
  }
  @media (max-width: 700px) {
    #logo {
      margin-top: 15px;
      width: 100%;
      font-size: 1.5em;
    }
  }
```

не закрили круговий скобки